# what's the difference between iterator and array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that takes a sequence of numbers and determines if all the numbers are different from each other.

This was my first attempt

```py
def differ(data):
    for i in data:
        print(i)
        for j in data:
            print(j)
            if i==j:
                return False
    return True

print(differ([1,23,4,1,2,3,1,2]))
print(differ([1,2,3,4]))
```

```
1
1
False
1
1
False
```

Apparently, the for loop didn't loop over all the numbers in the data. Why did this happen?

I wrote another function using range().

```py
def differ(data):
    for i in range(1,len(data)):
        print("i:",i)
        for j in range(i):
            print("j:",j)
            if data[i]==data[j]:
                return False
    return True
print(differ([1,2,2,4,53]))
```

```
i: 1
j: 0
i: 2
j: 0
j: 1
False
```

It works, however, I don't understand why my first attempt didn't work.

Comment: You return `False` as soon as you have a match, and in your first snippet you have both loops start with the first element,  Naturally, the first element is equal to itself.

Comment: in the first solution you re comparing the I and j. When the code runs I is 0(zero) and it prints I, and then inner loop has j which runs and prints j(zero).  and then since I and j are equal it returns False and exits.

Comment: You could just sort the array, and then make sure no two consecutive elements are equal.  That would only take one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your first attempt is that it will eventually compare the same number with itself.

In the sequence `[1,2,3,4]` the first function will start off with `i=1` and `j=1`. They are both looking at the first number in the list causing it to fail.

The second attempt avoids this by only looking at the numbers before it. `range(i)` doesn't actually include `i`, so `j` can only ever be less than `i` meaning they will never point to the same value in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think Tim Roberts answer explains perfectly why your code is not working as you expect. I would like to complement the answer:

## Answering your question

[Arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) are similar to lists, one of the differences is that the former consists only of elements with the same data type.
In the other hand, [iterators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp) are objects which you can iterate through, these objects must implement at least the following 2 methods on their respective classes: `__iter__()` and `__next__()`

## Cool way to do what you want in 1 line

You can achieve what you want with this:

```py
def differ(data):
    return len(set(data)) == len(data)


print(differ([1, 2, 3, 4]))  # True
print(differ([1, 23, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2])) # False
```

So basically, the magic here happens when you use `set()`. [Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) are similar to lists, but one of the main differences is that they can't have repeated elements. By transforming the `list` to a `set` you are removing every duplicated element, so if there is a difference in the length after casting to a `set`, it means there was at least one duplicated element.